# how to use an embedding theorem to show existence of a solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Can someone look at the **14th** line of page **9** [in this article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uam.es%2Fpersonal_pdi%2Fciencias%2Fmapperez%2Fultimos_trabajos%2FPerezPrimoRevised.pdf&ei=78m7VPjuFsP5UtKegnA&usg=AFQjCNEWUiwjrczoQQhswakkxluVyOuXHQ&sig2=8W3V033ABeiUkr3cxtf2Qw&bvm=bv.83829542,d.d24) and give a hint that how with the embedding theorem we could find $u\in W^{2,q}(\Omega)$ and how $u_n$ coverge strongly to $u$ in 
$W^{2,q}(\Omega)$ .

And also can you say that , why in **4th** line of page **9** of the same article , we could consider $u_n \in L^{\infty}(\Omega). $

And also how we can proof $\nabla v_n \to \nabla v (a.e.)$ in **10th** line of page **9** of same article.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to what the authors do in the previous paragraph, by standard regularity you get that $\{u_n\}$ is a bounded sequence in $W^{3,1}$. Now you can apply Rellich-Kondrachov theorem to the sequence $\{u_n\}$ to obtain what you need.

Comment: @ tks : Can you say it in a bit detail that how $ \{ u_n \} $ is bounded sequence in $W^{3,1}$ . so thanks